# React Router With Hooks-Unable to navigate to screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a Contact screen where pressing the "Continue" button should allow me to navigate to "Confirm" screen.
I have used {useHistory} from react-router, and have set the onClick() to history.push('file') but I am still unable to navigate to the desired screen.
Here's the Routes.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Review from "./ReviewScreen";
import Contact from "./Contact";


function Routes(props) {
           return (
            <Router history={props}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Contact} />
                    <Route path="/Review" exact component={Review} />
                    </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }

export default Routes;
```

Here's the Contact component:

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import './Contact.css';
    import routeChange, {useHistory, Redirect} from 'react-router';
    import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, NavLink, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
   function Contact() {

  const history = useHistory();

   return (
    <div className="Contact">
      <header className="Contact-header">

 <div className="ButtonAlign">
        
              <button className="button">Previous</button>
              {/*Pressing this button should navigate*/}
              <button className="button" onClick={()=> history.push("/Review")}>Continue</button>
                        
              <button className="button">Cancel</button>
        </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

Comment: What version of react router are you using?

Comment: "react-router": "^5.2.0",

Comment: Why use both ```react-router``` and ```react-router-dom```? Just use ```react-router-dom```. It's a react-router but with more improvements.

Comment: I could do that but it still won't fix this issue.

Comment: The string that you push in history.push is supposed to be the path of the web page, not the path to your code.  Like history.push(“/home”)

Comment: Linda, I tried doing that, I am no longer getting any error, but the issue still remains, the component is not loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy, You Don't Need to use props as history in your router tag because by default useHistory Hook is Connected to BrowserRouter just need the Router to be imported from BrowserRouter and Remove the Props it will Work.... Here is your App.js File (Modified)

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Review from "./ReviewScreen";
import Contact from "./Contact";
function Routes(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/Review" exact component={Review} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default Routes;
```